# matplotlib how to pass one label for each data array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a `step` plot, but this would happen with `plt.plot` as well:

I want to plot 3 datasets, i.e. an array of 3 columns:

```
datasets = np.array([[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.75],
    [2.5, 3.5, 2.1, 3]]).T
x = np.array([np.arange(4)]*3).T

# It might be convenient to only use the plot function for plotting
# *and* labelling these 3 datasets:

plt.step(x, datasets, label=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
plt.legend()
```

The problem is that the labels are not understood as separate data labels:

```
>>> plt.gca().legend_.texts
[Text(0, 0, "['column1', 'column2', 'column3']"),
 Text(0, 0, "['column1', 'column2', 'column3']"),
 Text(0, 0, "['column1', 'column2', 'column3']")]
```

I know it works with:

```
plt.step(x, datasets)
plt.legend(['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
```

but why not with the plot `label` argument ?

Comment: *Why?* - Because the label is assumed to be a string for a single plot element. Multiple labels are not supported as of now.

Comment: Right, it's not too hard to circumvent. Thanks for clarifying I haven't missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the `plt.legend` call, by passing the lines (returned from the `plt.step` and the corresponding labels:

```
datasets = np.array([[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
    [2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.75],
    [2.5, 3.5, 2.1, 3]]).T
x = np.array([np.arange(4)]*3).T

lines = plt.step(x, datasets)
labels = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
plt.legend(lines, labels)
plt.show()
```

Output figure:

[image]

Comment: Note that OP already points out using `plt.legend` (last code snippet).